# How to sort a list by the maximum of each sublist?

Tags: r

I have a list which contains a powerset:

```
> str(ps10)
List of 1023
 $ : int 1
 $ : int 2
 $ : int [1:2] 1 2
 $ : int 3
 $ : int [1:2] 1 3
 $ : int [1:2] 2 3
 $ : int [1:3] 1 2 3
...
```

How can I sort the outer list by some statistic on the inner list (e.g. min, median, etc.)? The list is created sorted by the maximum inner element using `HapEstXXR::powerset().` I want to keep the list structure for later use.

`sort`, `sort.list` and `order` don't accept lists. In SAS, I would  add the statistic as yet another column to a dataset and call a `PROC SORT` by list.statistic, list id, list elements. I haven't figured out how to do this efficiently in R, without creating auxiliary vectors to get the ordering.

Thanks

Comment: The answer below provides some explanation, but the one-liner answer is `ps10 = ps10[order(sapply(ps10, max))]`.

Comment: Thanks. That's far better than pseudo-SAS code I was using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `L` is a list defined as `L <- list(c(1,2), c(1,3), c(2,5), c(1,4))`, then you could use:

```
L[order(-sapply(L, max))]
```

Explanation:

- `sapply(L, max)` gets the maximum for each item in `L`
- Putting that inside `order` with a minus-sign gives you the (decreasing) order of the elements starting with the one with the highest maximum.
- Putting that in between square brackets reorders `L` in the wanted order.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the following list and you want to sort it decreasingly according to the maximum element.

`L = list(c(1), c(1,2), c(1,4), c(2,5))`

So in this case the order would be 4, 3, 2, 1.

If I understand your question correctly, you can simply iterate through the list and then use order:

`maxArray = rep(NA, length(L))
for(i in 1:length(L)) {
  maxArray[i] = max(L[[i]])
}
order(maxArray, decreasing = TRUE)`

which will correctly return `[1] 4 3 2 1`

Comment: A more R-like way would be to replace the `for` loop with `maxArray = sapply(L, max)`

Comment: And to finish off OPs request, "*without creating auxiliary vectors*", reordering the list would could be as simple as `L = L[order(sapply(L, max))]`.